# Add multiple text views in GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to add to text views in GridView but unfortunately just one of to is added .. I am tried to make another adapter to second TextView but same problem I think problem in this line in my adapter but I can't figure it out ..

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(catList.get(position));
```

So this is my GridView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#DDACA4A4"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/catGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="2">


</GridView>
```

And this is mainActivity java class

catGrid = findViewById(R.id.catGridView);

```
    List<String> catList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    catList2.add("subTitle 1");
    catList2.add("subTitle 2");
    catList2.add("subTitle 3");
    catList2.add("subTitle 4");
    catList2.add("subTitle 5");
    catList2.add("subTitle 6");

    CatGridAdapter2 adapter2 = new CatGridAdapter2(catList2);
    catGrid.setAdapter(adapter2);

    List<String> catList = new ArrayList<>();
    catList.add("Cat 1");
    catList.add("Cat 2");
    catList.add("Cat 3");
    catList.add("Cat 4");
    catList.add("Cat 5");
    catList.add("Cat 6");

    CatGridAdapter adapter = new CatGridAdapter(catList);
    catGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is my adapter

```
public class CatGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private List<String> catList;


public CatGridAdapter(List<String> catList) {
    this.catList = catList;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return catList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quizitem, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(catList.get(position));


    return view;
}
```

I am tried to find solution but I can't find any thing ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a model class, that will look like:

```
public class MyData {
private String cat;
private String SubTitle;

public MyData(String cat, String subTitle) {
    this.cat = cat;
    SubTitle = subTitle;
}

public String getCat() {
    return cat;
}

public void setCat(String cat) {
    this.cat = cat;
}

public String getSubTitle() {
    return SubTitle;
}

public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
    SubTitle = subTitle;
}
```

}

then inside you MainActivity class, you have to set you data and initialize your adapter like:

```
List<MyData> catList = new ArrayList<>();
catList.add(new MyData("Cat 1","SubCat 1"));
catList.add(new MyData("Cat 2","SubCat 2"));
catList.add(new MyData("Cat 3","SubCat 3"));
CatGridAdapter adapter = new CatGridAdapter(catList);
catGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

also you have to change in your adapter class constructor also,

```
private List<MyData> catList;
public CatGridAdapter(List<MyData> catList) {
this.catList = catList;
```

}

and do forget to change in the items xml class. you have to add two text view, on is title other could be subTitle there and use both text view in adapter class like this

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(catList.get(position));
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SubTitle)).setText(catList.get(position));
```

-Feel free to discuss if you have any query

Comment: First of all thank you very much ..
**Second** I did all what you coded to me and all is good but in **my adapter** i see this ..(https://ibb.co/4gxMVwd)..

Comment: Can you help please